# why can I not use a generic parameter to overload a function?

Tags: generics, swift, overloading, calayer

I have a layer that should respond to gestures.
So my UIView is forwarding all gestures to this function (in a CALayer subclass).

```
func handleGesture<T: UIGestureRecognizer>(gesture: T, atPosition position : CGPoint)
    {
        if let hitLayer = hitTest(position)? as? THGestureProtocol
        {
            if let tapGesture = gesture as? UITapGestureRecognizer
            {
                hitLayer.handleTapGesture(tapGesture, atPosition: position)
            }
            else
            {
                hitLayer.handleGesture(gesture, atPosition: position)
            }
        }
    }
```

This function then looks for the appropriate sublayer and forwards the gesture.

```
@objc protocol THGestureProtocol
{
    func handleGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer,    atPosition position : CGPoint)
    func handleTapGesture(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer, atPosition position : CGPoint)
    func handleDragGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer, atPosition position : CGPoint)
}
```

This code works but I had hoped to overload the call function like this

```
func handleGesture<T: UIGestureRecognizer>(gesture: T, atPosition position : CGPoint)
    {
        if let hitLayer = hitTest(position)? as? THGestureProtocol
        {
            hitLayer.handleGesture(gesture, atPosition: position)
        }
    }


@objc protocol THGestureProtocol
{
    func handleGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer,    atPosition position : CGPoint)
    func handleGesture(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer, atPosition position : CGPoint)
    func handleGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer, atPosition position : CGPoint)
}
```

This doesn't work. Only the first function is ever called. So why doesn't this work?

Comment: You probably need to use a `where clause` in your generic function statement. [See The Swift Programming Language: Where clauses](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_292).

Comment: Do you mean like this: handleGesture<T where T: UIGestureRecognizer>? No, that doesn't make a difference. It's the same as handleGesture<T: UIGestureRecognizer>

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is described here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/17580#17580

Long story short, function body is compiled with given information about T instead of a real type under T with which function was called. This is different approach than templates in C++.

```
class A {}
class B: A {}
class C: A {}

func f(_: A) {
    print("A")
}

func f(_: B) {
    print("B")
}

func f(_: C) {
    print("C")
}

func ff<T: A>(a: T) {
    f(a)
}

func gg(a: A) {
    f(a)
}
```

In this example functions **ff** and **gg** are equivalent.